# Comparison of positive elements and Hilbert C*-modules

Tags: modules, operator-algebras

I can't find a proof of facts like the following, which apparently are quite standard in the theory of C*-algebras.

Let $\mathfrak A$ be any C*-algebra, and $a,b$ two positive elements in $\mathfrak A$ such that $a\leq b$. Then

1. there is an inclusion of $\overline{a\mathfrak A}$ into $\overline{b\mathfrak A}$ as right Hilbert $\mathfrak A$-modules;
2. $\overline{a\mathfrak A}\equiv\overline{aa^*\mathfrak A}$.

I believe that the idea behind the proofs of these two facts is basically the same (I was thinking in terms of support of spectral projections). So the question is: how do you prove such facts, and similar properties for C*-algebras that are along these lines?

Any reference to existing literature is also welcomed.

Cheers!

Comment: Don't we need some hypothesis like $a<b$? Also, is $\bar{a\mathfrak A}$ the closure of $\{ax\,\mid\,x\in\mathfrak A\}$?

Comment: Indeed! Thanks to your comment I realised I missed that fundamental hypothesis.

Comment: And yes, the line on top denotes closure.

Comment: The problem with your parenthetical is that C*-algebras don't have to have projections.  In (2), is $a$ is an arbitrary element of $\mathfrak A$?

Comment: My thoughts are not thought through enough to want to post an answer, but for (2) I suggest trying to show that $a=\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\searrow 0}aa^*a(a^*a+\varepsilon 1)^{-1}$.  For (1), you could try to show that $a=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b^{1/n}a$, and for each $n>0$, $b^{1/n}=\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\searrow 0}b(b+\varepsilon 1)^{(1-n)/n}$.